# Error while trying Schedule new Update for a Product

Tags: magento2, product, error, upgrade, schedule

Trying  **Schedule new update** for a Product, I get this error after click Save:

> Error: : Something went wrong while saving the
>   Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface.

I have 2 environments Stage and Production, only happening in Production.

Does anybody know this problem?

[image]

Comment: Hi AlfredoGM, did y get the solution for it ?

Answer (score 0):

I was face this same issue and found that there was an conflict with 3rd party extension `sailthru` and this extension not handling the `multiple select type product attribute values`.

In that extension a plugin type `**Magento\Catalog\Model\Product**` used for after save method.

So find the code where the attributes fetched and than just implement the condition for `multiple select type product attribute values`.

like below:

```
if( $attribute->getFrontendInput() == "multiselect" ) {
    $attribute_code = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
    $storeId = $product->getStoreId();
    $attributevalues= $product->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($product->getId(),$attribute_code,$storeId);
    $data[$label] = explode(',', $attributevalues);
     } else {
    $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
    if ($value and $label and $value != "No" and $value != " ") {
        $data[$label] = $value;
    } }
```

Hope this will help you.